# Amadeus soap API authorized

Tags: amadeus

How can I generate Username password officeId to call Soap APIs
I have already enterprise account, but I couldn't find those properties
I don't have any experience about how can I use it, please tell me how can I  use SOAP APIs
If you have any example code for Node.js or Postman please share with me
Just for SOAP APIs

Comment: Hi @maziar, for questions about Enterprise APIs, you need to contact with the Enterprise Account Manager in charge of your company. He will help you for sure. In this channel we only offer support for Self-Service APIs.

Comment: Besides, you can use the following document: https://developers.amadeus.com/support/contact-us-enterprise